# <program_name> running <program_name.exe> on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

When I type a program name in Windows Command Line (e.g. `sfc`), the `sfc.exe` is executed. I understand that the program is in `Path` environment variable so it gets found. My question is how does `sfc` execute `sfc.exe`? Is this some aliasing?